# Regular expression for strings with a specific number of a certain character

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

Using Scrapy selectors (https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#regular-expressions), I'm trying to select elements of a web page with an `href` attribute that has a specific number of forward slashes, for example, `/foo/` or `/foo/bar/` (also always starting and ending with a `/`).

So far, to match relative URLs like `/foo/bar/`, I've come up with

```
In [24]: re.match('^/[^/]+/[^/]+/$', '/foo/bar/')
Out[24]: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 9), match='/foo/bar/'>
```

However, repeating this for an increasing number of slashes (e.g. `/foo/bar/bam/`) seems unnecessarily verbose to me. Is there a more succinct way of matching a string with a **given** number (not any number) of slashes?

Comment: You could use something simple `^/(?:[^/]*/)*$`

Comment: show your code with `test()` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex to match any number of subdirectories separated by `/`:

```
^(?:/[^/]+)*[^/]+/?$
```

- `^` - Start
- `(?:/[^/]+)*` matches 0 or more of `/` followed by one or more `non-/` strings
- `[^/]+` matches last component of a path
- `/?$` matches options `/` in the end

Comment: Thanks, but I'd actually like individual selectors for a **specific** number of subdirectories (e.g. 2, 3, ...). How could I do that?

Comment: In that case splitting is better approach instead of matching. Just split the path by `/`

Comment: The problem is that this has to be used in the `test()` function in a Scrapy selector, which only accepts regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

To get urls in the html body it is always a better idea to use [`LinkExtractors`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html):

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
...
le =  LinkExtractor(allow='^/(?:[^/]+/){2}[^/]+/$') # for links with 2 slashes
all_links = le.extract_links(response) # all links matching the `allow` regex.
...
```

You can also keep including rules inside the LinkExtractor to actually match better links.

Comment: Thanks, but in this case I'm trying to get the text within an `<a>` element, not the URL itself. (My selector is `response.css('.breadcrumbs').xpath('.//*[re:test(@href, "^/(?:[^/]+/){2}[^/]+/$")]/text()').extract_first()`, where the website is http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/cslskku/androbench-storage-benchmark/androbench-storage-benchmark-5-0-release/androbench-storage-benchmark-5-0-android-apk-download/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm a great deal slower than 'others' with regex. You did indicate that you wanted to check for a *specific* number of slashes. This seems to do it.

```
>>> import re
>>> link = '/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/bar/'
>>> n=5
>>> re.match(r'(?:/[^/]+){%s}/'%(n-1), link)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 17), match='/foo/bar/foo/bar/'>
>>> n=6
>>> re.match(r'(?:/[^/]+){%s}/'%(n-1), link)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 21), match='/foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava)'s answer, I used a non-capturing group with a specific number using the `{}`:

```
In [33]: re.match('^/(?:[^/]+/){1}[^/]+/$', '/foo/bar/')
Out[33]: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 9), match='/foo/bar/'>

In [34]: re.match('^/(?:[^/]+/){2}[^/]+/$', '/foo/bar/bam/')
Out[34]: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 13), match='/foo/bar/bam/'>
```

This way I can easily adapt the code to get a pattern for any number of slashes.